# Git Newbie - How often should I push to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, push, development-environment

I'm used to the traditional way of using FTP - where I simply upload a chaged file and refresh the page to view the changes.

However, is this OK to do so with Git? Or should I be running a local server on my PC then pushing a final, complete version to Heroku Master?

Comment: I found [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) regarding creating a staged environment. However, my concern still remains of 'over-pushing' for small tweaks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with whether you use FTP or Git. You push when you want users to see the changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git isn't a drop-in replacement for FTP. IMO you should always develop on a local system. Commit significant changes with useful comments as regularly as you can bear to. Push when you NEED to see the app in Heroku, or if you get paranoid that you need a remote backup of your Git repos.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just starting to understand the usefulness of Git - I can't believe I used to use ftp and folders to version my code

Answer (score 0):

If you develop along with others it is OK to push daily at the end of the day. So everyone will have a consistent repo on his own machine when pulling from the remote.